# MySQL creating temp table then join faster than left join

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a `LEFT JOIN` that is very expensive:

```
    select X.c1, COUNT(Y.c3) from X LEFT JOIN Y on X.c1=Y.c2 group by X.c1;
```

After several minutes (20+), it still does not finish. But I want all rows in X. So I really do need a `LEFT JOIN` at some point.

It appears that I can hack my way around this to return the result set I am looking for by using a temp table in less than two minutes. I first trim down table Y so that it only contains rows in the join.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table2 AS 
(select X.c1 as t, COUNT(Y.c2) as c from X 
INNER JOIN Y where X.c1=Y.c2 group by X.c1);

select X.c1, table2.c from X 
LEFT JOIN table2 on X.c1 = table2.t;
```

This finishes in under two minutes.

My questions are:

1) Are they equivalent?

2) Why is the second so much faster (why doesn't MySQL do this kind of optimization), meaning, do I need to do these kinds mysql?

EDIT: additional info: C1, C2 are `BIGINTS`. C1 is unique but there can be many C2s that all point to the same C1. As far as I know, I have not indexed any tables. X.C1 is an _id column that Y.c2 refers to.

Comment: not really. your temp table is an inner join, so you'll only get results where records existed on both sides of the join. the left join would return ALL matching left-side records and ANY matching right-side records.

Comment: But then I do do a left join.

Comment: @MarcB except for seeing nulls  for the count where the count is 0 his 2nd query seems like it should return the same results as the 1st because he's left joining the temp table

Comment: @Tommy can you include what indexes you have, `explain` output and the column types of the columns you're joining on as well as the # rows in your table

Comment: Edited. Also, C3 was not needed; counting C2 works as well, so I removed that.

Comment: Try indexing `X.c1` and `Y.c2` and running your original query

Comment: @FuzzyTree this SIGNIFICANTLY sped up the first query. Thanks!! I will use that. However, do you know why, if both tables weren't indexed, why the second would still be faster? Post as an answer and I will accept because the indexes solved my original slowness problem.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Yes, but C2 is not (there can be many C2s that all have the same C1).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try indexing X.c1 and Y.c2 and running your original query.

It's hard to tell why your 1st query runs slower without the indexes without comparing the query plans from both queries (you can get the query plan by running your queries with `explain` at the beginning) but I suspect it's because the 2nd table contains many rows that do not have a corresponding row in the 1st table.

Answer (score 0):

If `x.c1` is unique, then I would suggest writing the query as:

```
select X.c1,
       (select COUNT(Y.c3)
        from Y
        where  X.c1 = Y.c2
       )
from X;
```

For this query, you want an index on `Y(c2, c3)`.

The reason why a `left join` might take longer is if many rows do not match.  In that case, the `group by` is aggregating by many more rows than it really needs to.  And no, MySQL does not attempt this type of optimization.